# Sort vaadin grid containing text field as component column

Tags: grid, vaadin8, vaadin-flow, columnsorting, vaadin-grid

I am using vaadin 8. This grid contains a number of columns. Two columns are having textfield as component column because user wants to enter something in string format. Hence we use TextField component inside both columns. This is done by using **grid.addComponentColumn** method. Even after enabling setSorting(true), it seems that sorting is not working for both these columns.

```
    addComponentColumn(DataGrid::getUserMessage).setId("userMessage").setSortable(true).setCaption("UserMessage");
```

i have tried below two things but still it is not sorting.

First

```
addComponentColumn(DataGrid::getUserMessage).setId("userMessage").setSortable(true).setCaption("UserMessage").setComparator((p1, p2) -> p1.getUserMessage().getValue().compareTo(p2.getUserMessage().getValue()));
```

Second

```
addComponentColumn(DataGrid::getUserMessage).setId("userMessage").setSortable(true).setCaption("UserMessage").setSortOrderProvider(direction -> Arrays.asList(new QuerySortOrder("userMessage", direction)).stream());
```

Data grid is the class which contains column names and its setter/getters.
How can I make this work? Can someone demonstrate it by a snippet

Update below solution works! This piece of code is for improvement for sorting containin null values while using comparator

````
    @Override
    public int compare(final DataGrid a, final DataGrid b) {
        if (a.getUserMessage().getIntegerValue() == null && b.getUserMessage().getIntegerValue() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (a.getUserMessage().getIntegerValue() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b.getUserMessage().getIntegerValue() == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return a.getUserMessage().getIntegerValue().compareTo(b.getUserMessage().getIntegerValue());
    }
);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example,

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("Lucas", "Lucas Message"));
personList.add(new Person("Samuel", "Samuel Message"));
personList.add(new Person("Aaron", "Aaron Message"));

Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(personList);

grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");

grid.addComponentColumn(person -> {
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setValue(person.getMessage());
    tf.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
        person.setMessage(e.getValue());
    });
    return tf;
}).setId("customColumn").setComparator(
        (p1, p2) -> p1.getMessage().compareTo(p2.getMessage()))
        .setCaption("Message");
```

And the Person class

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String message;

    public Person(String name, String message) {
        setName(name);
        setMessage(message);
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Hi tarek i have done the same thing(see first example) but it is not working as expected

Comment: Hello, this example works for me in the sense that the column is sorted based on the value of the textfields. Could you please elaborate on the sense it's not working? Do you wish for the column to be re-sorted automatically once the textfield value has changed?

Comment: just in i have found that it is working correclty for vaadin textfield but in my code there is one custom class(extends vaadin textfield) which is validated by vaadin binder(if anything entered other than an integer value then it should not be allowd) and this might be the reason that comparator is not sorting the data in that field.

Comment: Could be a bug then if the sorting doesn't occur even if the validation passes

Comment: No issue due to binder! Found that if a number(Integer) is entered in vaadin text field then it is not sorted as expected even after calling setComparator. Is there any workaround available

Comment: Issue solved!! Works with setComparator as well :) found that for taking integer value from text field i need to use `getValue().getIntegerValue()` , then sorting works correctly

Comment: You can do so by replacing this expression in my example code: `p1.getMessage().compareTo(p2.getMessage()` with a code block (one that goes between curly brackets: `{code block}`). In this code block, you can do whatever you want, then return either a negative number if `p1<p2`, a positive number if `p1>p2`, or returns 0 if `p1==p2`

Comment: I have already tried this but the problem is that some rows of grid have message column value as null due to which null rows are present in between after sorting. How can we avoid or push grid rows which have message column values as null to bottom? In case of string this can be work but if someone puts an integer then there are null rows in between.

Comment: This is working but the only problem is that on sorting in ascending order it places null values before any number. While on sorting in descending order it is placing null value after numbers(I have updated the question. Please refer).